# PHP : Add durations

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to add an array of durations (video length) together to get the final length of the whole series.

The values will be in the `H:i:s` format:

```
$durations = array(
   '00:05:34',
   '00:03:26',
   '00:06:13',
   '00:05:15'
);
```

Is there any easy way of getting the total time for the values of this sort of array?

Comment: Convert the values to seconds, do an addition and then convert back to H:i:s.

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: I think I might use your suggestion as these values come in the time() format from Vimeo's API so it might be fairly easy to do it this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For quick and dirty implementation;

```
function AddTime(Array $durations) 
{
    $total_time    = 0;
    foreach($durations as $duration) {  
        sscanf($duration, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
        $total_time += isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
    }    
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($total_time/3600),($total_time/60%60), $total_time%60);;
 }

$durations     = array(
   '00:05:34',
   '00:03:26',
   '00:06:13',
   '00:05:15'
);

echo AddTime($durations);
```

Comment: I like this, it is a better solution and outputs `00:20:28`. **+1** - The 2 first zeros is a better output format.

Answer (score 1):

Here I have developed a duration calculation function. Just copy and past it.

```
<?php
function duration_cal($durations)
{
   $sec = 0;
   foreach($durations as $du)
   {
        $timarr = explode(":",$du);
        $hh = $timarr[0];
        $mm = $timarr[1];
        $ss = $timarr[2];

        $sec = $sec + ($hh*60*60) + ($mm * 60) + $ss;
   }

   $hh = floor($sec/3600);
   $mm = floor(($sec%3600) / 60);
   $ss = (($sec%3600) % 60);

   $hh = str_pad($hh, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $mm = str_pad($mm, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $ss = str_pad($ss, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

   return $hh.":".$mm.":".$ss;
}


$durations = array(
   '00:05:34',
   '00:03:26',
   '00:06:13',
   '00:05:15'
);

echo duration_cal($durations);
?>
```

Working script in this url: http://sugunan.net/demo/duration.php

Comment: `floor()`, not `round()`.

Comment: It [does not work correctly](http://codepad.org/fM6Cntgf), in that link you'll find that '00:05:34' is considered '00:06:34'.

Comment: @Wrillen: I have apply fix for the 2 digit issue. And the calculation also fine on my script. This is time calculation. not 10 based calculation.

Comment: Now that you've indeed changed `round()` to `floor()` as suggested, it works indeed, and the formatting fix is a nice bonus :). I have not a clue what you mean by this not being 10 based calculation. Calculations in themselves don't care what base you do this in, only displaying of results care about base. You are right if you mean we shouldn't display it as 100 minutes per hour instead of 60, but that was never an issue in your answer or in in my comment, so I have no idea why you bring that up.

Comment: @Wrikken: I'm not sure how the codepad.org works. But my script on my real php server gives correct calculation. http://sugunan.net/demo/duration.php and thanks for the notification on `round` to `floor` issue.

Comment: @Wrikken: I check the earlier code. It had some issue. Thanks for pointing out. But current code for same input working fine.

Comment: Yes, it now works, but not on that codepad link because I copied over your code without the `round()` vs. `floor()` fix, to demonstrate to you why it failed. That codepad page of course doesn't have you now edited fixes in it, and it doesn't need to: you've fixed your answer, it works correctly now, I see no reason to post that code to a new codepad snippet to demonstrate that the fixes work indeed ;)

Comment: Thanks to help to fine tune the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

#### Fun with [Date/Time](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$durations = array(
    '00:05:34',
    '00:03:26',
    '00:06:13',
    '00:05:15'
);

$startDate = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$endDate   = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

foreach ($durations as $duration) {
    list($H, $i, $s) = explode(':', $duration);
    $endDate->add(new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%sH%sM%sS', $H, $i, $s)));
}

echo $startDate->diff($endDate)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Spits out: `00:20:28`

Answer (score 0):

Found and taken/borrowed from source:
http://www.daveismyname.com/adding-multiple-times-together-in-an-array-with-php-bp

```
<?php 

class times_counter {

    private $hou = 0;
    private $min = 0;
    private $sec = 0;
    private $totaltime = '00:00:00';

    public function __construct($times){

        if(is_array($times)){

            $length = sizeof($times);

            for($x=0; $x <= $length; $x++){
                    $split = explode(":", @$times[$x]); 
                    $this->hou += @$split[0];
                    $this->min += @$split[1];
                    $this->sec += @$split[2];
            }

            $seconds = $this->sec % 60;
            $minutes = $this->sec / 60;
            $minutes = (integer)$minutes;
            $minutes += $this->min;
            $hours = $minutes / 60;
            $minutes = $minutes % 60;
            $hours = (integer)$hours;
            $hours += $this->hou % 24;
            $this->totaltime = $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
        }
    }

    public function get_total_time(){
        return $this->totaltime;
    }

}

// Your array
$times = array(
   '00:05:34',
   '00:03:26',
   '00:06:13',
   '00:05:15'
);

$counter = new times_counter($times);
echo $counter->get_total_time();

//outputs:
// 0:20:28
```

Comment: `floor()` might be more explicit/ readable then `(integer)`, you had me fooled at the start ;)

Comment: @Wrikken TBH, I found the code while Googling for possible answers for the OP. I guess I should have just put a link to that page in a comment. Would you like me to delete my answer? (It wasn't meant to fool anyone) lol

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is separated task from the logic you trying to implement and wrapped this as helper (or converter) class, the code is self explained:

```
class Helper_TimeAggregator {

    private $_durations = null;
    private $_seconds = null;

    /**
     * Constructor with init & constructor by default
     */
    public function __construct($durations = null) {
        if (isset($durations)) {
            $this->setDurations($durations);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Setter for init
     */
    public function setDurations($newDurations) {
        $this->_durations = $newDurations;
        $this->_seconds = null;
    }

    /**
     *  Returns total seconds
     */
    public function getTotalSeconds() {
        if (!isset($this->_seconds)) {
            if (!is_array($this->_durations)) {
                return '00:00:00';
            }
            $seconds = 0;
            foreach ($this->_durations as $duration) {
                $parts = explode(':', $duration);
                if (3 === count($parts)) {
                    $seconds += $parts[0] * 3600;
                    $seconds += $parts[1] * 60;
                    $seconds += $parts[2];
                }
            }
            $this->_seconds = $seconds;
        }
        return $this->_seconds;
    }

    /**
     *  Converts to data
     */
    public function getTotalTime() {
        return date("H:i:s", $this->getTotalSeconds());
    }

    /**
     *  Using default method by default
     */
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getTotalTime();
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
$durations = array(
   '00:05:34',
   '00:03:26',
   '00:06:13',
   '00:05:15'
);
$t = new Helper_TimeAggregator($durations);
echo $t;
```

All improvements are welcome!

Comment: Sidenote: It outputs `19:20:28` - I believe that should be `00:20:28`

Comment: It shows me exactly 00:20:28 like it should be, didn't you change anything?

Comment: No, I didn't change anything, that's what I find strange.

Comment: It's not clever to call `if(isset($durations)) {` since the variable will always exist thanks to the default value `null`. You should rather check if $durations is not null.

Comment: That's what exactly isset() does - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php - check for existance or null